# Stub out address geocoding during unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest, rails-geocoder

> This is my user.rb file, where I have use geocoded_by :full_address.Which give me follwing error on running minitest cases "ArgumentError: unknown stub request 2000 h st nw room 1 washington district of columbia 20037". Following is code of unit test.

```
def full_address
@address = ""
@address << " " << self.street_address_1.to_s unless self.street_address_1.blank?
@address << " " << self.street_address_2.to_s unless self.street_address_2.blank?
@address << " " << self.city.to_s unless self.city.blank?
@address << " " << self.state.name.to_s unless self.state_id.blank?
@address << " " << self.zip.to_s unless self.zip.blank?
@address.strip.downcase
```

end

```
  test "in_user_range? returns false if not in range" do
item = items(:protein_only_item)
user = users(:user2)
user.latitude = 41.542517 # west des moines ia
user.longitude = -93.760625 # west des moines ia
user.geocode
item.in_user_range?(user)
```

end

Comment: I just see a ruby method trying to return a long address string here.
Please copy your unit test as well, especially where you are trying to stub.

Comment: @rohan I have added my test cases too. On 'user.geocode' it give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

> We just need to add stub before geocode

```
Geocoder.configure(:lookup => :test)

Geocoder::Lookup::Test.add_stub(
 "New York, NY", [
  {
   'latitude'     => 40.7143528,
   'longitude'    => -74.0059731,
   'address'      => 'New York, NY, USA',
   'state'        => 'New York',
   'state_code'   => 'NY',
   'country'      => 'United States',
   'country_code' => 'US'
 }])
```